# How to deal with link2sd?

Tags: recovery-mode, insufficient-memory, link2sd

I installed link to sd and moved apps without creating the 2nd partition , do I must unistall my apps (I can't move them to internal storage),If I can do a recovery please tell me how!

Answer (score -1):

Download DU Speed Booster. It has some handy features such as move to SD and Safe Uninstall and will help you out.